# VPN connection using Hyper-V in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

How to enable Hyper-V to connect VPN for external internet access in Windows 8?
I'm trying to run Windows phone 8 app using emulator, and while see app in emulator it doesn't connect the VPN to access internet.

Please advice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has a [**troubleshooting**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681694%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_network) page for the Windows Phone 8 emulator. Perhaps you can find related info there. Something like this might help:

### Cannot connect to Internet destinations

> The Windows Phone 8 Emulator uses the HTTP proxy settings from the host computer. If you can’t access Internet resources from the emulator, check with your IT administrator to make sure that your proxy settings will work with the emulator.
>
> If your network’s proxy servers are unavailable or malfunctioning, it might be possible to restore connectivity for the emulator by disabling automatic proxy detection on the host computer. However this only works in certain network configurations.
>
> To disable automatic proxy detection on the host computer
>
> 1. On the host computer, open Internet Options from the Control Panel. The Internet Properties dialog box opens.
> 2. In the Internet Properties dialog box, click the Connections tab.
> 3. On the Connections page, click the LAN settings button. The Local Area Network (LAN) Settings dialog box opens.
> 4. In the Local Area Network (LAN) Settings dialog box, deselect all the check boxes. Click OK twice to close both dialog boxes.
> 5. Restart the emulator and retry the connection.

Also this MSDN blog-post can be helpful: [**Why can’t the Windows Phone Emulator go online?**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/10/01/why-can-t-the-windows-phone-emulator-go-online.aspx). Useful part of the article:

> As you see, clicking the “>>” on the bar parallel to the Emulator will open a small window with 4 tabs. The last tab is for “Network”. To explain in simpler terms, there are two adapters here – one is for internal use by Emulator and other is for external network connectivity. Each adapter will have an IP address (IPv4) associated with itself. The one of our interest is under Adapter #2.
>
> I have erased out the IPv4 address that is assigned to Adapter #2 (Yellow box), but you find that the IP assigned here starts with 169.254.x.x…., then Bingo! -  we have figured out the problem. How?
>
> The IP addresses starting with 169.254.x.x ….  Are usually the self-assigned default addresses to a device and not really helpful to get the device to go online.  This IP should either be a static IP or the one assigned by the DHCP server (if you have one in the environment) for the device to be able to connect to external networks.

Hope this helps.